# Computing Residues Confusion

Tags: complex-analysis

For $C := \left \{ |z| = 2\right \}$, $\int_{C}\frac{e^{\pi z}}{4z^2 + 1}dz$ the isolated singularities are $\pm \frac{1}{2}i$. By Cauchy Residue Theorem,$\newcommand{\Res}{\operatorname{Res}}$ $$\int_{C}\frac{e^{\pi z}}{(z + \frac{1}{2}i)(z - \frac{1}{2}i)}dz = 2\pi i \left ( \Res(f, \tfrac{1}{2}i) + \Res(f, -\tfrac{1}{2}i)\right )$$

Since $\frac{1}{2}i$ is a Simple Pole, then $\Res(f,\frac{1}{2}i) = \lim \left ((z- \frac{1}{2}i) \frac{e^{\pi z}}{(z+\frac{1}{2}i)(z - \frac{1}{2}i)} \right ) = 1$

However, an equivalent statement is that $\Res(f,\frac{1}{2}i) = \frac{p(\frac{1}{2}i)}{q'(\frac{1}{2}i)} = \frac{e^{\pi \frac{1}{2}i}}{4i} = \frac{1}{4}$

I should get the same answer for my residue, but I don't. Why not?

Comment: Is $q=(z+i/2)(z-i/2)$?

Comment: I differentiate $(z+i/2)(z-i/2)$ and I get $2z$, plugging in $i/2$ I get $i$. Why do you get 4i?

Comment: The singularities of $\frac{e^{\pi z}}{4z^2-1}$ are at $z=\pm\frac12$.

Comment: $\pm \frac{1}{2}$ is incorrect.

Comment: @Telon: now that it's been edited, yes, they are.

Comment: @robjohn That was my mistake. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}=\frac{e^{\pi z}}{(z+i/2)(z-i/2)}$$

Then, $q'(z)=2z$, which at $z=i/2$ is $$q'(i/2)=2(i/2)=i$$

Thus, $\frac{p(i/2)}{q'(i/2)}=1$

But the original problem had $\oint_C \frac{e^{\pi z}}{4z^2-1}$, which has singularities at $z=\pm 1/2$.  So,

$$f(z)=\frac{e^{\pi z}}{4(z-1/2)(z+1/2)}$$

The residues are given by $e^{\pi/2}/4$ and $-e^{-\pi/2}/4$

Comment: Hm, since the roots of $4z^2 + 1$ are $\pm \frac{1}{2}i$, then that means $4z^2 + 1 = (z + \frac{1}{2}i)(z - \frac{1}{2}i)$ right? So, if $q(z) = 4z^2 + 1$ then $q'(z) = 8z$.

Comment: Well, no. The function $q$ was expressed as $q(z) = (z+i/2)(z-i/2)=z^2+1/4\ne 4z^2+1=4(z^2+1/4)$.  Does that make sense?  So, both sides have the same zeros, but differ by a factor of $4$.

Comment: If we know the roots of a polynomial, we should be able to express the polynomial as a product of $(z-z_k)$. Does this not work for complex polynomials?

Comment: It does work, but the original function $f(z)=\frac{e^{\pi z}}{4z^2-1}$.  I've added to my answer to provide a way forward.

Comment: But we shouldn't have to add on a constant. Should it purely be a product of the roots?

Comment: $4z^2-1=4(z-1/2)(z+1/2)$.  We need the factor of $4$; it is part of the function.